# Check if calendar field is empty

Tags: javascript, html, primefaces

Ok so i have a calendar field:

```
<p:calendar id="dateOfBirth" mode="popup" placeholder="Date Of Birth" navigator="true" yearRange="c-18:c" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
```

And in javascript i want to check if the field has been entered a date:

```
if($("#dateOfBirth").val() === ""){
    errors.push("dateOfBirth");
}
```

But it is not working. How can i make this equality in order to check that the user has skipped the field without entering anything?

Comment: inspect the element's id does it  get the form id prefix? then surely it wont work.

Comment: I already checked that.It doesnt require the form id

Comment: can you add the compiled/generated element in the dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p:calendar` renders not just as a HTML `input` element. But it contains an `input` element which has the id you specified plus a postfix, which is `_input`. So your code should work if you change it to the following

```
if($("#dateOfBirth_input").val() === ""){
   errors.push("dateOfBirth");
}
```

Comment: I would recommand to select the input as $("#dateOfBirth input") because you know it contains an input but you don't define the id